# Parallax scrolling implementation

Tags: html, css, scroll, parallax

I followed a tutorial on parallax scrolling and have come up with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .parallax {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;
            perspective: 1px;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .parallax_layer_back {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 650px;
            top: -150px;
            background-size: cover;
            transform: translateZ(-1px);
            background-image: url(https://www.rgraph.net/images/front-page-sidebar-background1.jpg);
            background-position: 0px;
            margin: -250px -1500px 0 -1500px;
        }

        .parallax_layer_front {
            transform: translateZ(0);
            margin-top: 230px;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 25px;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="parallax">

        <div class="parallax_layer_back"></div>

        <div class="parallax_layer_front">

            <h1>Beautiful javascript charts for your websites</h1>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

But I've been unsuccessful at converting the layer at the top to a layer at the right-hand -side of the page like the one on the RGraph website: https://www.rgraph.net

Can anyone suggest how to do that?

Comment: Also, I have a setTimeout() based version of this - ie setting the background-position of an image every 25ms. Is this just a HORRIBLE version of the CSS way of doing things?

Answer (score 0):

Just change structure and css a lil bit.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.parallax {
    color:#fff;
}
.container{
  width: 950px;
  margin:0px auto;
  background: #00000070;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 50px;
}

.parallax_layer_back {

position: relative;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
padding:50px 0px;

}
.parallax_layer_one{
  background-image: url(https://www.rgraph.net/images/front-page-sidebar-background1.jpg);
}
.parallax_layer_two{
  background-image: url(https://www.rgraph.net/images/front-page-sidebar-background2.jpg);
}

.parallax_layer_front {
    transform: translateZ(0);
    margin-top: 230px;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Parallax Page</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="parallax">

        <div class="parallax_layer_back parallax_layer_one">
          <div class="container">
            <h1>Beautiful javascript charts for your websites</h1>

            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>
  
            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>
  
            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>
  
            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>
  
            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>
  
            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>
  
            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>
  
            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>
  
            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>
  
            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>
  
            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>
  
            <p>
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
            </p>
  
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="parallax_layer_back parallax_layer_two">
            <div class="container">
              <h1>Beautiful javascript charts for your websites</h1>

              <p>
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
              </p>
    
              <p>
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
              </p>
    
              <p>
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
              </p>
    
              <p>
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
              </p>
    
              <p>
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
              </p>
    
              <p>
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
              </p>
    
              <p>
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
              </p>
    
              <p>
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
              </p>
    
              <p>
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
              </p>
    
              <p>
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
              </p>
    
              <p>
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
              </p>
    
              <p>
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
                  guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu guy guy gyu guy gyu gyu gyu 
              </p>
    
            </div>
         
      </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That example isn't doing any parallax scrolling